Python asyncio.gather not really parallel?
So I am trying to understand the parallelism in asyncio.gather() function.
I have a FastAPI app that needs to upload 4 files to s3 at the same time.
I am using a local S3 for testing right now, so latency should be minimal, but I see different result numbers that confuse me a bit.
I ran each code sample 5 times and will past here the fastest execution of it.
Asyncio Gather with Partial:
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
start = time.time() * 1000
await asyncio.gather(
    *[
        loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            functools.partial(
                s3_client.upload_fileobj, file.file, "test", file.filename
            ),
        )
        for file in files
    ]
)
end = time.time() * 1000
print(f"gather time: {end - start}")

Executions:

125 ms
130 ms
119 ms
122 ms
132 ms

Asyncio Gather with tasks and separate async func:
async def s3_upload_fileobj_async(*args, **kwargs):
    return s3_client.upload_fileobj(*args, **kwargs)

start = time.time() * 1000
await asyncio.gather(
    *[
        asyncio.create_task(
            s3_upload_fileobj_async(file.file, "test", file.filename)
        )
        for file in files
    ]
)
end = time.time() * 1000
print(f"gather time: {end - start}")

Executions:

194 ms
163 ms
152 ms
168 ms
164 ms

Normal sync function:
start_total = time.time() * 1000
for file in files:
    start = time.time() * 1000
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(file.file, "test", file.filename)
    end = time.time() * 1000
    print(f"File: {file.filename} time: {end - start}")

end_total = time.time() * 1000
print(f"Total time: {end_total - start_total}")

Executions:
Separate file execution time run 1:
 1. File 1 upload time: 32.92822265625 
 2. File 2 upload time: 41.922119140625
 3. File 3 upload time: 39.576904296875
 4. File 4 upload time: 49.405029296875


Total sync execution time run 1: 163ms
Total sync execution time run 2: 222ms
Total sync execution time run 3: 162ms
Total sync execution time run 4: 182ms
Total sync execution time run 5: 156ms

Observations:

Asyncio Gather with Tasks is roughly the same as fast as Sync code.
Asyncio Gather with partials is faster than all approaches.

Questions:
Since the per file time to upload is from 32ms to 49ms, if Asyncio gather starts all the executions at the same time, the expected time to finish would be the longest file upload time, right?
49ms(longet file upload) vs 163ms (Asyncio gather with Tasks)
49ms(longet file upload) vs 125ms (Asyncio gather with partials)


How come Asyncio gather with Tasks is almost the same performance as Sync code where we wait for each file to upload separately and continue with the next? Are tasks using asyncio gather actually not run in parallel all at the same time?

Thanks

async is not parallel. It just means cooperative multitasking - that while you're waiting for IO to finish, your (or the library's code) says "OK, I'm just waiting for IO - so run some other code in the meantime". It does not make sync code run in parallell - it requires cooperation from the code you're running. You need an async-compatible s3 library that you can await when it runs the io part of the code. You might want to look at https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/ in that case.

But then why is it working here without using aioboto3? https://joelmccoy.medium.com/python-and-boto3-performance-adventures-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-aws-api-interaction-22f625ec6909

I know async is not parallel, but I thought using async + asyncio.gather() I can simmulate parallelism. I guess concurent doesn't mean parallel and I guess because of the GIL, you actually cannot easily run parallel code.

@doglover1337 has nothing to do with the GIL, you can't run parallel code with asyncio because that's not what it's for. For a longer explanation of concurrent vs parallel, see this answer. You say you understand the difference, but you seem to keep expecting one to be the other....

Made it work using threading
import threading

def upload(temp_file, filename):
    s3_client = boto3.session.Session().client(
        "s3",...
    ) # Make sure to initialise your s3_client inside the function, you need one new session per thread
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(temp_file, "test", filename)

for file in files:
    temp_file = io.BytesIO(file.file.read())
    threading.Thread(target=upload, args=(temp_file, file.filename)).start()

Response time around: 65ms for all files. Which is great, down from average of 160ms.
And this is all in development, I expect in production (with Gunicorn) to be even faster.

In addition to the link provided above, I would suggest having a look at this, as well as this and this, as they might prove helpful with regard to uploading files to S3.

You might also find this answer helpful.

Thanks a lot @Chris there are indeed very helpful ! Thanks for taking the time to search and share them.
